# ExpressJS Using URL as Handlebars Expression

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars view that is a form set that I am trying to manipulate to populate the fields of the form with values if the user is using the form from my `/edit/:annotation_id` route. I originally thought something like passing an object, `editMode: req.originalUrl` and using that as the condition would work, but I have had no success. I'm curious as to what approach I should take to only show forms with populated values if it is coming from the `/edit/:annotation_id` route and then a blank form if it is not. Any suggestions?

routes:

appRoutes.route('/')

```
.get(function(req, res){

    models.Annotation.findAll({
        where: {
            userId: req.user.user_id
        },
        attributes: ['annotationId', 'name'],
        order: 'annotationDate DESC'
    }).then(function(annotation){
        res.render('pages/high-level-activity-feed.hbs',{
            annotation: annotation,
            user: req.user,
            message: req.flash('Flash is back!')
        });
    })
})

.post(function(req, res){

    models.Annotation.create({

    name: req.body.name,

    }).then(function() { 
        res.redirect('/app');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
    })
});
```

appRoutes.get('/edit/:annotationId', function(req, res){

```
console.log('This is the url path ' + req.originalUrl);

models.Annotation.find({
        where: {
            userId: req.user.user_id,
            annotationId: req.params.annotationId
        },attributes: ['name']
    }).then(function(annotation){
        res.render('partials/edit-modal.hbs',{
            annotation: annotation,
            user: req.user,
            editMode: req.originalUrl
        });
    })
});
```

annotation-form.hbs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Add a new annotation</h2>
        <div class="annotation-form">
            {{#if editMode}}
            <form action="/app/edit/{{annotation.annotationId}}" method="post">
                <div class="annotation-form-header">
                    <img class="user-image" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <label for="annotation-date">name</label>
                    <input type="date" name="name" id="name" value="{{annotation.name}}">

                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="update-button">Update</button>
            </form>
            {{else}}
            <form action="/app" method="post">
                <div class="annotation-form-header">
                    <img class="user-image" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <label for="annotation-name">Name</label>
                    <input type="date" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="create-button">Create</button>
            </form>
            {{/if}}

        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about handlebars - but have you tried ejs integration with express?

There are only about four things you'd need to do to integrate it:
 1. Add the following to your package.json and run npm install:

```
"ejs": "^2.3.4",
"express-ejs-layouts": "^2.0.0",
```

2. Update your app to use ejs:

> ```
> var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
> app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
> ```

3. Your render code can remain essentially unchanged - but here is a simplified version:

> ```
> res.render('pages/test.ejs',{
>     editMode:true
> });
> ```

4. Then update your view/html page with the ejs syntax:

> ```
> <%if (editMode) { %>
> in editMode your html looks like this
> <%
> }
> else{
> %>
> In non editMode your html looks like this
> <%}%>
> ```